# Can I say "Getting some rest after a long week of back-breaking work can replenish you with a new burst of energy."?

Tags: word-choice, word-request

I was writing an essay on the importance of relaxing, and why it is more productive than working nonstop.

I wrote the following sentence:

> Getting some rest after a long week of back-breaking work can
>   replenish you with a new burst of energy.

I sense that there is something weird with the way I used "**burst**". I've seen people using the expression "**a burst of energy**", but it just feels misplaced here.

Is there any better alternative for this word? Or, perhaps, a better way to communicate the message I tried to convey in that sentence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally do not feel that 'replenish' and 'burst' are particularly related. To me 'replenish' is quite a calming action, however 'burst' is too bold here. 
I think it would be better to maybe say 'Getting some rest after a long week of back-breaking work can replenish you, giving you a new burst of energy'.